# How to create AWS resources based on an existing ARN using CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I'm wondering is there a way to create AWS resource in CloudFormation template using existing ARN (Amazon Resource Name).

For example, I already have a Dynamo DB whose ARN is something like `arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:111111111111:table/MyTable`. Now I want to create a table in CloudFormation which essentially is pointing to this existing DynamoTable. May be something like:

```
Resources:
  MyTable:
    Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
    ARN: 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:111111111111:table/MyTable'
```

I know the code above doesn't work, but does anyone know how can I achieve this? Lots of thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to "connect" a new Cloudformation template to existing AWS infrastructure.

You'd have to create a new DynamoDB with your template and migrate the data over.